# InvalidRequest in ApiRequestor.php line 103: No such plan: small; one exists with a name of small, but its ID is 1

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-cashier

In my stripe account, customer generated, test payment is also made. In my app, user table populated with stripe details.

But subscriptions table is not updated in DB, now its telling me:

> InvalidRequest in ApiRequestor.php line 103:
>   No such plan: small; one exists with a name of small, but its ID is 1.

Here code in my controller"

```php
$creditCardToken=$request->input('stripe-token');
Auth::user()->newSubscription('main', $request->input('plan'))->create($creditCardToken);
return "done";
```

Comment: now its done, the only problem remain is in subscriptions table trial_ends_at and ends_at fields are null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a subscription on the Stripe dashboard you need to input both a unique ID and a Name.

In this case you have set the ID to '1' and the name to 'small' so Stripe is telling you there is no plan with that ID but there is one with a name of small, which is kind of a nice hint.

If you want to refer to the plan you have there you need to either update the ID of the Stripe plan to 'small' or update your form request to reference the plan as ID '1'.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you mike. I will take a look at your answer.